# Total variation of a complex measure is a positive measure (Rudin proof)

Tags: real-analysis

[image: total variation is a positive measure proof]

Hi everybody
Im trying to prove this theorem from rudin.
I have two difficulies

1. what gives us to right to put $\sum_{i}t_i$ in $(\star)$, this is a sum of real numbers maybe it doesnt exist?
2. In $(\star\star)$ i think he did
   $$sup\{\sum_{i}t_i~~,~~(t_i)_{i}\text{ sequences in }\mathbb{R}\text{ such that }t_i<|\mu|(E_i)\}=\sum_i |\mu|(E_i)$$
   but how to prove this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally we can require $-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i \leq t_i < |\mu|(E_i)$

This additional restriction makes $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \max(0,-t_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i = 1 < \infty,$$ so that $\sum_i t_i$ exists [as an extended real number].

---

Immediately from $t_i < |\mu|(E_i)$ we have $\sum_i t_i < \sum_i |\mu|(E_i)$ and therefore, since the right-hand side is independent of $(t_i)$, we have $$\sup_{(t_i)} \sum_i t_i \leq \sum_i |\mu|(E_i)$$

To show equality, let $t_i = |\mu|(E_i) - \epsilon\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i$ for $0 < \epsilon < 1$ to see $$\sum_i t_i = \sum_i |\mu|(E_i) - \epsilon$$ so $$\sup_{(t_i)}\sum_i t_i \geq \sum_i |\mu|(E_i) - \epsilon.$$ Now, let $\epsilon \to 0^+$.

Comment: thank youuu sir